Connect-SPOService broken Popup: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden
when I run Connect-SPOService -Url https://xxx-admin.sharepoint.com
I get a dialog box asking me to pick an account
I click on + use another account and then I enter my admin email address
It shows Taking you to your organization's sign in page then the popup disappears, then I get
Connect-SPOService : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
I was recently upgraded to Windows 11 (the module worked with Windows 10)
Exchange, Teams, and Azure, Azure AD, Graph powershell module all still work correctly.
I have tried with ISE PowerShell version 5.1.22621.2506
and Visual Studio code Powershell Version 7.0
The SharePoint module I am using is version 16.0.24810.12000 (I have tried other versions)
I was able to get ISE working once when I loaded Fiddler with Proxy enabled, then disabling fiddler but I can no longer recreate that.
I opened a ticket with Microsoft, but they are less than helpful.
